# Loading Django apps for development

Tags: python, django, django-models, python-module

So, I've got this set-up in which I installed a django project (the directory containing the settings.py and manage.py) in the site-packages directory of my python installation. I've done this to use apps from other packages, which works nicely. 
I noticed however, that when I'm developing, the development server (manage.py runserver) loads files from the site-package directory.

Example:
There is a file, views.py, that loads models from models.py using:

```
from models import Project, Test
```

Because of a small error within the production code I tried to fix, still pops up within the development server, and the django error page (such a nice feature) shows the old code from the file that's installed in site-packages. So, I put in this line:

```
import models
print models.__file__
```

and the result of that is exactly the file I want, from my development directory. The next line, from models import Project, Test loads models from the site-package directory, which is totally not what I want.

I guess I've polluted the namespace, I'm guessing that the from-import imports already loaded imports from memory, but that the normal import-line imports a module that isn't in memory yet. This apparently leads to the strange effect of being successfully able to change views.py and see the changes in the development server.

Anybody's got any idea how to fix this?

System info:

- Python2.7
- Django1.3
- Debian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/index.html) is for. It creates isolated development environments, and is indispensable for working on multiple projects/versions at once.

Comment: This was the final push I needed to start using this. Implemented it today and yesterday, and contrary to my expectations, it was really easy to set up! And watching numpy and scipy compile never bores!